# Add empty line before and after every object (table, graphic, algorithm)

Tags: spacing

How can I add empty line before and after every graphic, table, and algorithm? I have managed to find something like this:

```latex
% Load the floatrow package
\usepackage{floatrow}
% Set the spacing around algorithms
\floatsetup[algorithm]{capposition=top,skip=10pt}
% Set the spacing around graphics
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top,skip=10pt}
% Set the spacing around tables
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top,skip=10pt}
```

But it doesn't even compile - `Undefined control sequence`

Edit

Fixed - use this:

```latex
% Load the caption package
\usepackage{caption}
% Set the spacing around algorithms
\captionsetup[algorithm]{aboveskip=10pt,belowskip=10pt}
% Set the spacing around graphics
\captionsetup[figure]{aboveskip=10pt,belowskip=10pt}
% Set the spacing around tables
\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=10pt,belowskip=10pt}
```

Comment: please provide an example, we can not run your fragment and you have not shown the error message which would have said which command was not defined.

Comment: please dont add answers to the question, it spoils the site format. You can post a self-answer

Answer (score 1):

See length `\intextsep`. It is vertical space between floats and surrounding test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength\intextsep{2\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe use the `\vspace{Xmm}` where X is the size of the empty space you want